# Output Error (Duplicates) Powershell

Tags: html, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, powershell

My query results are to my understanding not being saved/forwarded correctly. What should be happening is that for each server (svr01,svr03,svr05,svr06,svr08) I should be getting their OS, Full Domain Name, and etc. Then this information is meant to populate my SQL database (Hal0Test). However, that information is never being sent and I do not know how to fix this.

I added a small html output to my powershell script in order to LOCALLY see my results. The html is just easier for me to open then running SQL Server Management Studio and refreshing that program. But I still want all those variables to be sent to the database.

**Goal**: Correct the duplicate issue **and** start sending that information to my sql database. If you can help me that would be AMAZING!

**Code:**

```
Write-Output " `n Start of Hal0 `n";

#Start of Server Connection
$connectionString = "Server=QAUTILITYDB01;Database=Hal0Test;Integrated Security=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()

$ServerArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$query = "SELECT ServerName FROM ServerList"
$command.CommandText = $query
$ServerNames = $command.ExecuteReader()

$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($ServerNames)

$ServerArray = $table | select -Expand ServerName

#Variables for each Server in Array
$ServerArray | ForEach-Object {
    # $ServerArray returns each server name

    #Operating System
    $os    = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Computer $_ 
    #Server's Memory (RAM) Usage Average
    $memAvg    = gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $_ | 
    Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }} 
    #Server's CPU (Proccess) Usage Average
    $cpuAVG = Get-WmiObject -computername $_ win32_processor |  
    Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average 
    #Server's Hard Drives (MB) Free/Used
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Computer $_ |
             Where-Object {$_.DriveType -eq 3} |
             ForEach-Object {
                 '{0} {1:D} MB Free/{2:D} MB Used' -f $_.DeviceID,
                     [int]($_.FreeSpace/1MB), [int]($_.Size/1MB)
             }

    New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property @{
      'FQDN' = $_
      'ServerName' = $os.PSComputerName
      'OperatingSystem' = $os.Caption
      'CPUAvg' = "$($cpuAVG.Average)%"
      'MemAvg' = "$($memAvg.MemoryUsage)%"
      'Disks'  = $disks -join ' | '
    }

    $command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_', OS = '$($os.Caption)' WHERE ServerName = '$($os.PSComputerName)';"
    $result = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()

 Write-Output " `n Start of Hal0 `n";

#Start of Server Connection
$connectionString = "Server=QAUTILITYDB01;Database=Hal0Test;Integrated Security=True;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()

$ServerArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$query = "SELECT ServerName FROM ServerList"
$command.CommandText = $query
$ServerNames = $command.ExecuteReader()

$table = new-object “System.Data.DataTable”
$table.Load($ServerNames)

$ServerArray = $table | select -Expand ServerName


#Start of HTML Code
$Outputreport = 
                "<HTML><TITLE> IDI Server Report </TITLE>
                <BODY background-color:peachpuff> 
                <font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""> 
                <H2> IDI Server Report </H2></font> 
                <Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> 
                <TR bgcolor=gray align=center> 
                    <TD><B>Server Name</B></TD> 
                    <TD><B>FQDN</B></TD>
                    <TD><B>CPU Usage</B></TD> 
                    <TD><B>RAM Usage</B></TD> 
                    <TD><B>Disk Space</B></TD> 
                    <TD><B>Operating System</B></TD>
                <TD><B>Query result</B></TD></TR>" 
$ServerArray | ForEach-Object {
    # $ServerArray returns each server name
    # collection code skipped
    $command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_', OS = '$($os.Caption)' WHERE ServerName LIKE '$($os.PSComputerName)%';"
    $result = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    if($cpuAVG.Average -ge "2")  
      {  
        $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=#FF0000>"  
      }  
    else 
      { 
        $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=#E6E6FA>"  
      } 
    $Outputreport +=
        "<TD>$($os.PSComputerName)</TD>
        <TD align=center>$($_)</TD>
        <TD align=center>$("$($cpuAVG.Average)%")</TD>
        <TD align=center>$("$($memAvg.MemoryUsage)%")</TD>
        <TD align=center>$($disks)</TD>
        <TD align=center>$($os.Caption)</TD></TR>
        <TD align=center>$($result)</TD></TR>"

}
    $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"  
    $Outputreport | out-file C:\Users\king\Desktop\HalO\ServerReport.html
    Invoke-Expression C:\Users\king\Desktop\HalO\ServerReport.html
    }

Write-Output "`n End of Hal0";
#End
```

**HTML Results:**

[image]

**SQL Database:** FYI I manually added in "char"

[image]

Comment: There is a lot of information here and I'm not sure which parts are actually relevant. Is the problem solely with your SQL query? Are you seeing errors when you try and insert to the table?

Comment: Sorry for that but my issue is my program as you can see in images is making duplicates instead of getting information from each of 5 servers. But Idk why because in the console it is pulling the correct information from each server. But it seems like my ServerArray is not storing the results correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the HTML-based report inside the outermost foreach-loop in full, but your `$_` is only limited to the current server being processed. Instead, put wrapper HTML into `$Outputreport` prior to the start of your main loop, then add a `<tr>...</tr>` part with current data within the loop. And drop the second loop on `$ServerArray`. Also include the `$result` in your report, apparently all update queries result in `0 row(s) updated` and you don't see why. (A wild guess: encoding mismatch (UTF16 vs database's UTF8)) Probably you might decide to `INSERT INTO ServerList` the data and drop old rows, so that your keyfield will certainly be consistent.

```
#Start of HTML Code
$Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE> IDI Server Report </TITLE>
                <BODY background-color:peachpuff> 
                 <font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""> 
                 <H2> IDI Server Report </H2></font> 
                 <Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> 
                 <TR bgcolor=gray align=center> 
                   <TD><B>Server Name</B></TD> 
                   <TD><B>FQDN</B></TD>
                   <TD><B>CPU Usage</B></TD> 
                   <TD><B>RAM Usage</B></TD> 
                   <TD><B>Disk Space</B></TD> 
                   <TD><B>Operating System</B></TD>
                   <TD><B>Query result</B></TD></TR>" 
$ServerArray | ForEach-Object {
    # $ServerArray returns each server name
    # collection code skipped
    $command.CommandText = "UPDATE ServerList SET FQDN = '$_', OS = '$($os.Caption)' WHERE ServerName LIKE '$($os.PSComputerName)%';"
    $result = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    if($cpuAVG.Average -ge "2")  
      {  
        $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=#FF0000>"  
      }  
    else 
      { 
        $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=#E6E6FA>"  
      } 
    $Outputreport += @"
        <TD>$($os.PSComputerName)</TD>
        <TD align=center>$($_)</TD>
        <TD align=center>$($cpuAVG.Average)%</TD>
        <TD align=center>$($memAvg.MemoryUsage)%</TD>
        <TD align=center>$($disks)</TD>
        <TD align=center>$($os.Caption)</TD></TR>
        <TD align=center>$($result)</TD></TR>
        "@
    # used a here-string for clarification  
} 
$Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"
```

I've also changed where clause to a like statement, probably your DB has FQDNs in `ServerName` column.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! With your code I was able to push to the server but sadly it is only for the last row in the serverlist. I am doing something wrong. I editted my question to reflect the new code and errors.

Comment: Why did you drop collection code? I've shortened the code in the answer into a comment, as it wasn't needed to patch that segment, and now you have `code skipped` in your question :)

Comment: Do a `Write-Host $ServerArray` right after receiving it from the database. According to HTML report, your server array has only server 08 repeated 5 times. Also, I have edited your collection code back into the question for you.

Comment: That worked PERFECTLY. I will check on the server end and report back